# SQL - complex grouping query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, grouping

I have a series of records that need to be grouped.  Here is a sample of the  data:

```
System   TYpe     Batch#      TX_ID     MatchingTX_ID   AcctID  
   HB      0      1113       395505                     700002008159    
   PB      2      1113        82546                     405002031125  
   PB     32      1113        82546      82436          405002031125  
   PB     20     21298        82436      82546          405002031125
```

The desire is to group these records together in a report.  The issue is that there is not a common field value to all columns.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your desire result? Take some time and explain what you want to do and what have you tried  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You have to be grouping them some how. Otherwise its just a SELECT or an ORDER the point of grouping, is putting together ones that share a similar value. I'm not understanding what you're trying to accomplish.